# Commutative Diagrams in Table of Figures

Tags: floats, table-of-contents, diagrams, captions

Should one treat *commutative diagrams* as figures within the `figure` environment? If not, is there a way to add a label/caption and have the page number and caption show in the Table of Figures (without the `figure` environment)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there aren't many of the diagrams, it's better to just use `figure` for all of them. If the number is significant and you want to distinguish them from other figures, you can use, for example, the [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) package to create a new type of floats:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}

\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{commut}{tbp}{loc}
\floatname{commut}{Commutative diagram}

\begin{document}

\begin{commut}
  \caption{Hello World}

  I am the content
\end{commut}

\listof{commut}{List of Commutative Diagrams}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to create a new float for CDs but have them show up in Table of Contents in the front matter? The code you gave only shows the \listof after the CDs.

Comment: @user02138: You can put `\listof` anywhere you like, just as `\listoffigures` etc. Only remember to run LaTeX twice at least.

Answer (score 3):

If you treat them like figures (caption, entry in list of figures) you could also use a figure environment, that would just be consistent.

Regarding the placement, you still can customize it by options to the figure (some of `!htbp`). If they are small, they can be easily placed by LaTeX. If they are big, there's even more reason to let them float.

If you don't want them to float, you can use for example a minipage and the `\captionof` command of the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package, such as

```
\captionof{figure}{Your diagram caption}
```

Here a minipage is good for keeping caption and diagram together without a page break between.

`caption` provides a `\DeclareCaptionType` command, you could use it to create diagram environments and a list of diagrams, if you like. Also even if you `float` instead, `caption` offers a lot of features and a great interface for customizing captions.